# D3.js Rotating a map breaks styling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, map-projections

I am trying to rotate a globe (orthographic projection).
What I have now does rotate the globe, though it is very choppy, and it breaks how the map looks after i drag it (graticules and ocean fill)

How can I improve my code to make it better?
Here is the relevant code:

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');

const projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
const graticule = d3.geoGraticule();
let pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);


const g = svg.append('g');

g.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'sphere')
    .attr('d', pathGenerator({type: 'Sphere'}));

g.append('path')
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", pathGenerator);

g.call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));


g.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
   g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
 }));

function dragstarted(){
  console.log("started");
}
function dragged(){
  const rotate = projection.rotate()
    const k = 75 / projection.scale()
    //console.log(k);
    projection.rotate([
      rotate[0] + d3.event.dx * k,
      rotate[1] - d3.event.dy * k
    ])
    pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)
    svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", pathGenerator)
}
function dragended(){
  console.log("drag ended");
}
```

edit:
Live demo: https://vizhub.com/Glebenator/f44ac266b14f4c92b88113fcc89c389d?edit=files&file=index.html

Comment: Do you have a live demo or a JSFiddle or something? It would be helpful to see what you mean by 'breaks how the map looks'.

Comment: Fair enough, I will try to make one.

Comment: Also the map actually looks more smoth on the demo website than my local machine...
I think I just need to update all the elements properly when dragging, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Okay.. is this the look you are going for? https://vizhub.com/jgphilpott/59c2c92f1ad840268f99be8bbcae00b1?edit=files&file=index.js

Comment: Might also be a problem of SVG. You could also use a canvas renderer, see the great example from Mike Bostock: https://observablehq.com/@d3/versor-dragging

Comment: I believe I got all the components rotating smoothly together.. if this is the effect you were wanting i'll explain what I did in an answer.. if not let me know what i'm missing and i'll keep working on it.

Comment: yes @JacobPhilpott that looks great!

Comment: @Gleb, you'll see perfomance gains as well if you use `110m.json` rather than `50m.json` from the topojson atlas - the level of detail in 50m is in excess of your resolution given the sizing of the globe.

Comment: also if you don't mid. In the code demo, I was also trying to get a country name by clicking on it, but the on click listener does not seem to return the name. What am I doing wrong there? Because i can append the text with the country...

Comment: @AndrewReid Is it possible to dynamically change them if I zoom in for example?

Comment: @Gleb, you could use different files for each zoom depth no problem - there are still optimization tricks you might want to employ to avoid projecting all the data that extends beyond the frame though. That should probably be a separate question - however, I could, sometime later tonight, provide a number of options for optimizing your rotation first though (if others don't beat me to it).

Comment: @Gleb I've posted my answer and upvoted your question.. as far as the on click event listener is concerned I MIGHT try and help you out with it tomorrow but i’m going to bed now, it's late here.

Comment: @AndrewReid I would love to hear your advice on how to avoid projecting all the data that extends beyond the frame! In a separate project that I'm working on I have a large full screen map with multiple layers and it has a tendency to get a little laggy. If I post a question about that maybe you could provide your answer?

Comment: Hey @AndrewReid I just posted a fresh question to ask about how you can avoid projecting data that extends beyond the frame.. if you have any tips or tricks that would be awesome! https://stackoverflow.com/q/67109209/1544937

Comment: @JacobPhilpott, will take a look this week, have a few suggestions.

Comment: @AndrewReid that would be great! I look forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I did two things.

1. Inside of the `dragged` function instead of selecting all the path elements as one I selected them individually... so replace the line `svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", pathGenerator)` with `svg.selectAll(".graticule").attr("d", pathGenerator)` and `svg.selectAll(".country").attr("d", pathGenerator)`.
2. When you append the countries you use selectAll('path') like this `g.selectAll('path').data(countries.features)` ... I think this confuses d3 because you have already appended some path elements so I changed it to a unique selector like this `g.selectAll('.country').data(countries.features)`.

I'm not 100% sure why d3 behaves like that (maybe @AndrewReid can shed some light) but i've learned from experience that it's best practice to use unique selectors when appending and updating SVG elements with d3.